# PessimisticLockException when saving data in loop

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am getting pesimistlockexception when trying to persist multiple object of same time through JPA.
Here is my code for reference

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public Boolean changeDplListMappingByCustomWatchList(List<Integer> dplIds, Integer customWatchListId,
    ServiceRequestor customServiceRequestor) {

            for(Integer dplId : dplIds) {
                if(dplId != null) {
                    CustomWatchListDplMapping customWatchListDplMapping = new CustomWatchListDplMapping();
                    customWatchListDplMapping.setDplId(dplId);
                    customWatchListDplMapping.setWatchListId(customWatchListId);

                    this.create(customWatchListDplMapping);
                }
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception occured while changing dpl mapping by custom watchList id", e);
    }

    return true;
}

public void create(Model entity) {
    manager.persist(entity);
    manager.joinTransaction();
}
```

After first entity when it iterate through second one it throws an exception. If it has only one entity to save then it works well, but for more than one entity model it throws this exception.

Comment: What type of bean is this? How is the entity manager created? Have you tried removing `manager.joinTransaction()` or put it before the loop? My guess is that you're persisting stuff in different transactions, thus a pessimistic lock is present.

Answer (score 0):

by default pessimistic lock is for 1 second so please do the changes in the properties file it will help you to unlock and you will be able to save into database